# Program crashes when using scanf to read strings

Tags: c++, scanf

My program always crashes after the 5th scanf in the class function.

```
class PersoenlicheDaten{
    public:
        void eingabe(){
            printf("Bitte geben sie jetzt ihre Persoenlichen Daten ein: \n\n");
            printf("Vorname: ");
            scanf("%s", &vorname);
            printf("Nachname: ");
            scanf("%s", &nachname);
            printf("Alter: ");
            scanf("%d", &alter);
            printf("Geburtsdatum: ");
            scanf("%s", &geburtsdatum);
            printf("Addresse: ");
            scanf("%s", &addresse);
        }
    private:
        std::string vorname;
        std::string nachname;
        int alter;
        std::string geburtsdatum;
        std::string addresse;
};
```

Inside `main`:

```
do{
    pd.eingabe();
    printf("Sind sie mit der eingabe zufrieden?\n\n");
    printf("Antwort(j/n): ");
    scanf("%c", &v.antwiederholen);
    if(v.antwiederholen == 'j'){
        v.running = true;
    }else{
        v.running = false;
    }
}while(v.running);
```

Why is that because it should normally work. Also i want to use scanf instead of std::cin to learn different methods of input.

Comment: `scanf` `%s` takes a `char *`, not a `std::string *`.

Comment: `if (COND) { var = true; } else { var = false; }` better written as `var = COND;`.

Comment: Never use `scanf` for user input. If you do use `scanf`, always check its return value.

Comment: `Persoenlichen` shouldn't be capitalized; it's an adjective. But `eingabe` should be because it's a noun.

Comment: Use cin and cout.

Comment: *Also i want to use scanf instead of std::cin to learn different methods of input.*  -- I want to learn to drive a car with the handbrake on instead of releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you can't use `scanf` to read `std::string`. You will have to either convert your `std::string` to `char *`, or use `cin`. Another thing you could do, is to first read from scanf to a temporary `char *`, and then convert it to `std::string`, by doing something like:

```
scanf("%s", &someCharPointer);
std::string s = someCharPointer;
```

As a comment, there is nothing wrong with trying to learn how to use different things. Both `scanf` and `cin` have their own adventages and disadventages.

Answer (score 0):

To read string using scanf you actually have to have buffer big enough to read string.

```
char temp[100];
std::string vorname;
if(scanf("%99s", temp) ==1){
    vorname = temp;
}
```

With scanf you have to limit number of chars to read to match your temp buffer and check the return value before using buffer read. When reading from istream using getline or operator>> directly into std::string - your string variable will grow to match the user input